# XPages with a datasource from a view in a database on another server fails

Tags: datasource, xpages

I have an XPage which contains a view in a database which resides on another server.
When some users (administrative access = plenty rights) login they see the view - no problem.
When other users do they get the "Unable to open database" in the browser. 
All these users have access to both databases but not via the XPage.

Where do I look? The source server must be trusted since it works for some users.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of things to check:

1. Make sure that the XPage server is listed as *Trusted Servers* field in the server document of View server (even if it works for admins it's good to check this).
2. The XPage *server* must be in the ACL of the View database. I believe *Readers* is enough but if it does not work then try with higher access levels.

Comment: Thank you Panu Haaramo - I will try that and get back with the result!